# PHP loop to echo all Joomla article id's

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.5

With my very basic PHP knowledge I'm trying to make a module for Joomla V1.5. I am not quite into all the Joomla classes and methods but perhaps you can help me out.

What I'm trying to do is create a php loop which echo's all the article id's (and some html) from a certain category.
Normally I would do this by calling on the content table from the Joomla db but to make the code a bit more tidy I want to use the Joomla classes for this.
Can anyone point me the right direction which classes and methods to use for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no classes for handling the selection of the articles.

So it comes down to using a query and looping through the result set:

> $catId = 59; // the category ID
>
> $query = "SELECT * FROM #__content WHERE catid ='" . $catId . "'"; // prepare query
>
> $db = &JFactory::getDBO(); // get database object
>
> $db->setQuery($query); // apply query
>
> $articles = $db->loadObjectList(); // execute query, return result list
>
> foreach($articles as $article){ // loop through articles
>
> ```
>     echo 'ID:' . $article->id . ' Title: ' . $article->title;
> ```
>
> }